# Calculating Values Using Microsoft Access IIf Function

Tags: calculated-columns

I am creating a MS Access database to assign numeric values to various columns in a table using the `IIf()` Function.

The problem I am having is that the calculation is not providing a numeric value, it appears to be Boolean.

Below is an example code and results:

SMR Ind: `IIf([SMR Rating]="N/A",1.5,0) Or IIf([SMR Rating]="B",1.2,0)`

[image]

If `SMR Rating` is `B`, I would like the output to be `1.2` not `-1`.

Comment: `IIf([SMR Rating]="N/A",1.5,IIf([SMR Rating]="B",1.2,0))` or `Switch([SMR Rating]="N/A",1.5,[SMR Rating]="B",1.2,True,0)`

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Akina Please consider posting your comment-answer as an actual answer, so that it can be accepted and provide valuable content for the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Variant 1

```
IIf([SMR Rating]="N/A", 1.5, IIf([SMR Rating]="B", 1.2, 0))
```

Variant 2

```
Switch([SMR Rating]="N/A", 1.5, [SMR Rating]="B", 1.2, True, 0)
```